# Linux server rebooted without any traces ? How to find RCA for it

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

The server is rebooted and there are no logs in `/var/log/messages` and `last -f` for the reboot.

Power and hardware issues are considered the primary stage. All system admin level and Redhat things have been taken care of. I need something out of the box if anything there because this issue is untraceable.

I have already checked the RHEL support case, and they said no traces of the reboot, and `journalctl` also are not able to help. No panic or anything which can say it rebooted.

How can I get reboot reason?

Comment: RHEL comes with its own professional support. Have you check the documentation / asked the support?

Comment: Doesn't `journalctl` help? There are other logs under /var/log` that you can look at. Given RHEL, does the server have IPMI? If so, then interrogate that.

Comment: I have already checked the RHEL support case, and they said no traces of the reboot, and journalctl also are not able to help. No panic or anything which can say it rebooted.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of a power failure? In that case o log has been generated, obviously.

Comment: Yes, power and hardware issues are considered the primary stage. All system admin level and Redhat things have been taken care of. I need something out of the box if anything there because this issue is untraceable

Comment: Welcome to the community. SE sites aren't discussion boards. Instead of answering a clarifying question with a comment, the right way is to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768380/edit) your question to add new info as I now did for you. This way everything relevant is readily available for consideration. Things like "all system admin level and RedHat things" is open to interpretation; the more detailed the info, the better the answers you can expect.

Comment: Thanks i will ask there